# Expo SQLite how to insert a row and return the id of the just inserted row

Tags: react-native, sqlite, expo

I created the following function to insert a workout into my database.

```
  const date = new Date().getDate();
  let id;

    await db.transaction( tx => {
          tx.executeSql( 'INSERT INTO workouts (name, created_at) values (?, ?)',
              [name, date]

              ,(transact,resultset) => {id = resultset.insertId, console.log('we made it', id )}
              ,(transact,err) => {console.log('We have encounter an Error', err)}

    );
    });

    //it does not return the id
    console.log("id before return" + id)
    return id;
}
```

I want to return the id of the just inserted row, but it does not work, undefined is returned. However the line console.log('we made it', id )} does print the id correctly.
The function is called from the following code:

```
const handleAddWorkoutModal = async (workoutName, setShowAddWorkoutModal, router) => {
  try {
    const id = database.insertWorkout(workoutName);
    console.log(id);
    setShowAddWorkoutModal(false);
    router.push({
      pathname: '/pages/workouts/createWorkout/CreateWorkout',
      params: { workoutName: workoutName, workoutId: id}
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn(e);
  }
}
export default handleAddWorkoutModal;
```

I have also tried using the RETURNING statement from SQLite, but there are some issues with it atm.

> https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/24283

Could you help me out?

Comment: The database transaction is async and has to be awaited. Your code prints "id before return" first, right? The block inside the callback hasn't run yet when you return.

Comment: Even when I await it, it still prints the id before return first..  I think I have to work with a promise here, but I cant make it work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had to use a promise for the await to work properly.

```
const insertWorkout = (name) => {
  const date = new Date().getDate();
  let id;
    return new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
        db.transaction( tx => {
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO workouts (name, created_at) values (?, ?)',
                    [name, date]
                    ,(transaction,resultSet) => {id = resultSet.insertId, console.log('we made it', id )}
                    ,(transaction,err) => {console.log('We have encounter an Error', err)}
                );
            },
            (t, error) => { console.log("db error inserting exercise"); console.log(error); resolve() },
            (t, success) => { resolve(id)}
        )
    })
}
```

.then was used to get the value in the function calling in the insert.

```
const handleAddWorkoutModal = async (workoutName, setShowAddWorkoutModal, router) => {
  let id;
  try {
    database.insertWorkout(workoutName).then(value => {
      console.log("id" + value);
      id = value;
    })
    setShowAddWorkoutModal(false);
    router.push({
      pathname: '/pages/workouts/createWorkout/CreateWorkout',
      params: { workoutName: workoutName, workoutId: id}
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn(e);
  }
}
```